# HTML5 video won't play on Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, webm

I am working on a web project in HTML5 and I want to play a video in my web page. Here is my code:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls">
     <source src="assets/img/placeholder_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
     <source src="assets/img/placeholder_video.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

I noticed that the video isn't working on Google Chrome but it's working fine on Edge. I did not try on any other browser though.

I tried running the code on incognito mode (without extensions) and the problem is the same. I tried to put the webm source before the mp4 source, still the same problem. I tried writing autoplay="autoplay" and only autoplay, did not change a thing. My Chrome version is the latest.

The codec is H264 for the mp4 video, which it seems isn't supported anymore on Chrome, hence the fallback with the webm file. The webm file was converted from the mp4 file so I converted the original MOV file to webm directly with codec V8 and it does not work either. I also tried to remove completely the mp4 source to see if the webm only worked. It didn't.

Does anyone has an idea for me to try

**EDIT**
The problem is really that the video is not playing, but I can see the first frame. Even with `autoplay`, `autoplay="autoplay"` or `autoplay="true"` flags.

**EDIT 2**
I did a codePen with my code and it works fine. So the problem was with some script/css file I included in my project that I did not put in codePen. I tried commenting out every includes and it worked. Then I gradually integrated back my includes and found that when I included back the jQuery file, the video stuck on the first frame again. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: Maybe try `autoplay = "true"`?

Comment: Same problem sadly

Comment: Could you try with another video in a supported format to check that the problem is not with your video? You can check a list of the supported formats [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: Ok I tried with the demo video here: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html

And all I see is the first frame, even with the autoplay flag

Comment: Could you make a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) with your code?

Comment: http://codepen.io/gbastien1/pen/WGNgrE

it works T.T  although the codePen does not have all the JS and CSS files I included. Could it be because of Bootstrap, scrollmagic.js or a script like that ? :/

Comment: take a look in the developer tools tab... are there any errors in the javascript console, or the network. Does your jQuery library do anything with the video element?